# Google webmaster tools API python

Tags: python-2.7, gdata-api, google-search-console

I am using gdata2.0.18 webmaster tools API python to extract data. It is working fine for both

```
selected_downloads = ['TOP_QUERIES','TOP_PAGES']
```

I am trying to include CONTENT_KEYWORDS as follows.

```
selected_downloads = ['TOP_QUERIES','TOP_PAGES','CONTENT_KEYWORDS']
```

But there is only two .CSV file (for `top_queries` and `top_pages`) getting created. It is not happening for Content Keywords.

I am using only [example-simple-download.py](https://github.com/Venkateshwaran/WebMasterTools/blob/0526f2cb3a10844ea78f3d2c516546be4cceea6b/example-simple-download.py)

Here is my full library of code I am using : [GITHUB](https://github.com/Venkateshwaran/WebMasterTools/tree/ce8792566c50ff1db551ef933553b38d9f8ee17c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python API does not support `content_keywords` download in its present form. However,
you can modify http request in the downloader.py to include additional parameters to meet your needs. This way you can fetch `content_keywords` as well.

Furthermore, there is a PHP API that supports extracting content_keywords data, which you can search in Google. [link](https://code.google.com/p/php-webmaster-tools-downloads/)

Moreover, there is an extension of the current Python API that extracts data based on custom date ranges automatically for all registered web sites. 
[Find out more about it](http://amintor.com/1/post/2013/11/technology-extend-python-library-for-google-web-master-tools.html).